# How do alexa skills earn money if they are free, but amazon services have a cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot, alexa-voice-service

We are considering using voice commands to activate entry to a car park using Alexa.

I have seen that there are costs for using aws iot services and it is based on the number of devices and the number of transactions.

At first I thought that the user would pay this cost through a subscription to a skill that we are developing.

However, we are still not sure how much that subscription would cost.

I have tried to know what the system of some manufacturers of smart lamps that can be controlled with Alexa is like and I have seen that their skills are apparently free on Amazon.

So my question is:

How do they earn money to maintain the aws iot service?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about business models and not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

In-skill purchasing lets you sell premium content, such as game features and interactive stories in custom skills. You can offer in-skill products with the following payment models, One-time purchase, Consumable, Subscription. If you want to create in-skill products, more information can be found here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/in-skill-purchase/isp-overview.html